# IDataErrorInfo Combobox

Tags: wpf, idataerrorinfo

My Customer Model is as below. Customer Model contains validation attributes

**CustomerModel.cs**

```
[IsRequired()]
CustomerID - Int;
[IsRequired()]
CustomerName - String;
```

**CustomerViewModel contains 2 properties as below**
1. ObservableCollection of CustomerModel (This is bound Items Source of drop down list)
2. Property returns CustromerModel object as Selected Item (Bound to SelectedItem)

**My Question:**
How can i provide `ValidatesOnDataErrors=true` for combo box?

Do i need to write validation attribute on CustomerModel property inside CustomerViewModel?

Please suggest...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDataErrorInfo is a type specific implementation of Validation (vs. instance specific). You would be better off using ValidationRules. This link should help on how to implement ValidationRules:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.validationrules.aspx

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution. After searching on net i found a blog on worldpress - input-validation-ui-exceptions-model-validation-errors. I need to modify this code to make working with my requirement. I am accepting your answer.